# Reference error : process is not defined when using @metamask/sdk in a vitepress project

Tags: process, vite, metamask

I'm using vitepress and `@metamsk/sdk` package together in a project, but seems metamask will install a package named `util` that has some problems with process.

I've tried to put `export default window.process = process` and it solved but doesn't build because of window is undefined on server side.

Any ideas?